# jQuery Mobile - Correct way to use onclick on buttons?

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my app I have a button that I press that brings back some data, it works fine in my web browser but running it on my phone doesnt seem to work at all - whats the reason for this and can anyone tell me the correct way to do this?

```
<a href="" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="refresh" data-theme="b" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Generate</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way would be:

**HTML :**

```
<a href="" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="refresh" data-theme="b" id="some-button">Generate</a>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('click','#some-button',function() {
    loadXMLDoc();
});
```

Inline javascript event binding should not be used when working with jQuery Mobile. solution I provided you will work even if element don't exist inside the DOM.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/25NUK/

Comment: For some reason this is not working either, http://www.xbox1forums.co.uk/lotto/generate.php

Comment: You sure? I can see it working in your code, it generates numbers and shows them on the top.

Comment: It works just fine on iPad and iPhone, just checked it. Tell me, when you test it do you do it directly from that link or are you coming from some other page and testing then? This is an important question.

Comment: Whilst testing in the browser I'm going directly to it. I'm also testing in a native app that I have to click links to go to it - none seems to be working for me :(

Comment: Sorry I don't know where are you testing it but it works in every browser I used. From desktop, iOS to Android devices. First check if your mobile device can assess an internet. If this is not the case we still have one option. Also add an alert('asdas'); to your click event to see if button is really working or is it a problem with an ajax call?

Comment: :( just tried it with the alert, no luck (it's working fine on my desktop browser) I tried it on here: http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/ and it doesn't seem to work either, also my xcode emulator - quite strange!

Comment: got it to work, by putting it in a valid jquerymobile span :D - thanks for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31115/discussion-between-iyugshell-and-gajotres)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NR2ES/)

```
<a href="" class="testbutton" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="refresh" data-theme="b">Generate</a>


$('.testbutton').click(function() {
      loadXMLDoc();
  });
```

Comment: Thats not working for me, which I thought it would of (I tried this from a previous resource I found)

Comment: You sure you've defined any class name or id to your link?

Comment: the code it grabs is just:

function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","gen.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

Comment: I just copied your exact lines